# Can a Shul collect payment from one who does not follow specific rules?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, money, synagogue, choshen-mishpat-civil-law

In [Sources to encourage returning s'farim to their places](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47554/sources-to-encourage-returning-sfarim-to-their-places) it has a picture of a sign saying that usage of seforim is on condition that one obligates himself to pay $18 to the synagogue fund if they are not returned to their proper place. Is this enforceable according to Halacha?

Comment: Why would it be different than any other stipulation? As long as its obviously serious, of course.

Comment: @user6591: 1 - The Seforim were donated to be used, not to be returned to their location. 2 - The Shul is not the owner, it is owned by the community.

Comment: @Gershon Gold but the sponsor lets the Shul decide to endorse whichever rules they wish.

Comment: @GershonGold, if your question is meant to apply in the specific conditions listed in your comment, I recommend that you [edit] this post accordingly before someone answers the more general question that you posted.